# deferred chaining, Node.js and q, one single ErrorHandler for all chain-parts

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q, deferred

I have a design like this:

```
var postCommand = function(req, res){      
    parseForm(req)
    .then(checkData)
    .then(findCommand)
    .then(initializeCommand)
    .then(saveToDb)
    .then(onUploadSucceeded.bind(this, res))
    .fail(onUploadFailed.bind(this, res));  
}
```

the methods within the then's can potentially reject. I want that nothing will be executed anymore after a reject occured but the last .fail.

my "checkData" looks like this (yea its the only synchronous part in the chain):

```
var checkData = function(args){
    var deferred = q.defer();
    var fields = args[0];
    var files = args[1];
    var file = args[1].uploadedFile0;
    var secondFile = args[1].uploadedFile1;    
    if(file.type !== "application/javascript"){
        return deferred.reject("please only upload javascript-files");
    }
    (...)
    return deferred.resolve([fields, file]);
}
```

even when the deferred.reject is called, I end up in "findCommand" without arguments passed. Am I understanding something wrong with this chains?

Also the question: Is this design a good pattern? Or is there a other/better best practice?

Comment: You should really be doing response validation inside of each `then(...)` statement of your promise. If the response does not contain what is expected, then you break the promise chain.

Comment: But every fail callback would do the same... calling "onUploadFailed" with the error passed to the reject. This seems for me just like code duplication and decreases the readability. I thought of throwing an exeption instead of rejecting as the q-documentation says the "catch" method catches any error of the above chain. But thes seems a bit smelly

Comment: I use bluebird, so I'm not sure, but I think you should be returning deferred.promise in all cases.

Comment: this worked! I wonder why I didnt try that. Thank you (see my answer below)

Comment: I believe Q should be avoided before it's too late. What would `deferred.resolve(42)` return if not a promise?

Comment: @Redu `undefined` of course. Why would it return a promise? Maybe you're looking for `Q.resolve`/`Q.reject` when you want to create promises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `checkData()` was at the start of the promise chain, then it would need to be written as in your [own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39793615/3478010), returning an explicit promise.

In mid-chain it will also work when written like that, however mid-chain gives you better options on what to write.

More specifically, you can avoid the need to create and return a promise by :

- throwing instead of returning a rejected promise,
- returning data instead of promise-wrapped data.

So, providing `checkData()` is never used elsewhere to start a promise chain, it can be written thus :

```
var checkData = function(args) {
    var fields = args[0],
        files = args[1],
        file = args[1].uploadedFile0,
        secondFile = args[1].uploadedFile1;    
    if(file.type !== "application/javascript") {
        throw new Error("please only upload javascript-files"); // always throw an Error object, thus emulating a natural Error. This error will percolate down to the `.fail(onUploadFailed.bind(this, res))` handler.
    }
    (...)
    return [fields, file]; // the next step in the chain will assimilate a promise or data. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As adviced by Keith in his comment it was a syntax problem, solution:

```
var checkData = function(args){
    var deferred = q.defer();
    var fields = args[0];
    var files = args[1];
    var file = args[1].uploadedFile0;
    var secondFile = args[1].uploadedFile1;    
    if(file.type !== "application/javascript"){
        deferred.reject("please only upload javascript-files");
    }
    else{
        deferred.resolve([fields, file]);
    }        
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: Given that the function is synchronous, you shouldn't use deferreds at all. Either use `Q`/`Q.reject` to create fulfilled/rejected promises, or just `return` and `throw`, which has the same effect when `checkData` is used as a `then` handler.